# the best place to manage state in redux

Tags: redux

redux is described as a suite of tools to manage state but where is the best place to manage state.

I can either:

1. Create an initalState each time the start apps.
2. Store the state in local storage etc.
3. Load it from the db or perhaps render the inital state from a server call.

Any thoughts on the above?

Comment: You can do any of these 3 things, they are all viable answers, assuming you are talking about "initing" your state. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. I think if you make this question a little more specific it will be easier to give you answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "manage" state, it will be living inside your browser. If you want to "store" state, the answer is ALL OF THE ABOVE. There's a difference between managing and storing. If you want to load a user specific state at the start, you can get the state from either local storage, db or any other way you can think of. It's really up to you!